# How do I do the prismjs diff highlight with language in my markdown file

Tags: markdown, diff, syntax-highlighting, prismjs, codehighlighter

This (```js) for JavaScript language

This (```diff) works for diff.

But I don't know I to use both in my markdown file. I'm trying to achieve this in the docs https://prismjs.com/plugins/diff-highlight/